# Is it possible or worth sending an array to another method c#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

In my code I have two methods, one is the main method and the other is 'MethodA'. In the main method, I will be doing all the displaying an other functions from MethodA. However, in MethodA I am attempting to read in several files into an array and return them to the main method so they can be used. The questions I am asking are: (I have condensed my main method down for this question, it does include other items that don't link in this)

1: Is it worth reading the files into an array?

2: Should I just have the 'ReadFiles' in the main, instead of another method?

```
static void Main(string[] args) // THE MAIN INCLUDES MAINLY ONLY THE WRITELINES AND WHAT IS SEEN
        {
string value = MethodA();
           Console.WriteLine(value);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public string[] MethodA() //FILE METHOD - READS IN THE FILES THEN RETURNS THEM TO MAIN METHOD
        {
            StreamReader dayFile = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\Day.txt"); StreamReader dateFile = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\Date.txt");
            StreamReader sh1Open = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Open.txt"); StreamReader sh1Close = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Close.txt");
            StreamReader sh1Volume = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Volume.txt"); StreamReader sh1Diff = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Diff.txt");
            StreamReader sh2Open = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Open.txt"); StreamReader sh2Close = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Close.txt");
            StreamReader sh2Volume = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Volume.txt"); StreamReader sh2Diff = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Diff.txt");

            string dayString = dayFile.ReadToEnd(); string dateString = dateFile.ReadToEnd(); string Sh1OpenString = sh1Open.ReadToEnd(); string Sh1CloseString = sh1Close.ReadToEnd();
            string Sh1VolumeString = sh1Volume.ReadToEnd(); string Sh1DiffString = sh1Diff.ReadToEnd(); string Sh2OpenString = sh2Open.ReadToEnd(); string Sh2CloseString = sh2Close.ReadToEnd();
            string Sh2VolumeString = sh2Volume.ReadToEnd(); string Sh2DiffString = sh2Diff.ReadToEnd();

            string[] fileArray = new string[] { dayString, dateString, Sh1OpenString, Sh1CloseString, Sh1VolumeString, Sh1DiffString, Sh2OpenString, Sh2CloseString, Sh2VolumeString, Sh2DiffString };
            return fileArray;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Seems unnecessarily complicated the way you're doing it.

Comment: Do you need all file's content at the same time parallel? Then most likely yes.
However if you need them -at least some sequentially- then no, spare the memory.

Comment: I believe so, I'm using File.ReadAllText because I need to read all of the text in the specific files, then in the future I need to be able to search and sort the files, am I correct using that?

Comment: In the future, I will be adding a search - which will allow the user to search by date, and that specific date should show a specific string of text from each file.

Comment: Does this compile? You are assigning a stringarray to the string variable `value`.

Comment: If you only need certain attributes of each file you could create a corresponding class and store only what you need in there (header, date, values,...). This will make the data easier to access later on and might take up less of your memory (depending of how much of the filecontent you actually need)

Comment: It compiles now because I have changed 'string value = MethodA();' to ' string[] value = MethodA();'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is fine to read them all in - unless you know if the files are massive.

I'd do it this way:

```
    public string[] MethodA()
    {
        var filenames = new []
        {
            "Date.txt",
            "Day.txt",
            "SH1_Close.txt",
            "SH1_Diff.txt",
            "SH1_Open.txt",
            "SH1_Volume.txt",
            "SH2_Close.txt",
            "SH2_Diff.txt",
            "SH2_Open.txt",
            "SH2_Volume.txt",
        };

        return
            filenames
                .Select(fn => File.ReadAllText("c:..\\Files\\" + fn))
                .ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on wether the files tend to be rather small or not. If they are several gigabytes big, you are going to have a problem. In this case, you should instead try to sequentially read the files.

```
  public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(Stream stream)
  {
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
     {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           yield return line;
        }
     }
  }
```

BTW: StreamReader should always be used with the "using" keyword, as it otherwise leaves files opened until the garbace collector has finalized the instances that have gone out of scope.